# How to correctly set up a project directory for Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've looked at numerous tutorials and videos taking one through the process of generating documentation using Sphinx, and at this point I am convinced that there is something wrong with my project structure. I am running Windows 10 Pro, 2004; Python 3.7.9; Sphinx 3.3.0.

I created a completely fresh project `sphinx_test` to test my Sphinx skills by following these steps:

1. Create a new virtualenv `python -m virtualenv sphinxtest`
2. Activate it `sphinxtest\Scripts\activate`
3. Install Sphinx and requirements `pip install sphinx`
4. Create a new project folder `mkdir sphinx_test` and navigate into it `cd sphinx_test`
5. Create subdirectory for source code and all sub-modules to come `mkdir src`
6. Create some silly sample `*.py` files with random docstrings (`nopes.py` and `sqrer.py`)
7. Create the docs directory `mkdir docs` **and** navigate into it `cd docs`
8. Execute `sphinx-quickstart --ext-autodoc`, choosing separate `build` and `source` directories
9. Modify `conf.py`, adding  `./src/` to the `PATH`
10. Modify `index.rst`, adding `modules` beneath `toctree` group:

[image: modules beneath toctree]

11. Run `sphinx-apidoc -o .\source\ ..\src\` from inside the `docs` directory.
12. Run `make html` and get the following:

```
Running Sphinx v3.3.0
    loading pickled environment... done
    building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
    building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
    updating environment: 0 added, 2 changed, 0 removed
    reading sources... [100%] src
    WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'nopes' from module 'src'; the following exception was raised:
    No module named 'src'
    WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'sqrer' from module 'src'; the following exception was raised:
    No module named 'src'
    WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'src'; the following exception was raised:
    No module named 'src'
    looking for now-outdated files... none found
    pickling environment... done
    checking consistency... done
    preparing documents... done
    writing output... [100%] src
    generating indices... genindex done
    writing additional pages... search done
    copying static files... done
    copying extra files... done
    dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
    dumping object inventory... done
    build succeeded, 3 warnings.
    
    The HTML pages are in build\html.
```

This is the folder structure at present:

```
C:.
├───docs
│   │   make.bat
│   │   Makefile
│   │
│   ├───build
│   │   ├───doctrees
│   │   │       environment.pickle
│   │   │       index.doctree
│   │   │       modules.doctree
│   │   │       src.doctree
│   │   │
│   │   └───html
│   │       │   .buildinfo
│   │       │   genindex.html
│   │       │   index.html
│   │       │   modules.html
│   │       │   objects.inv
│   │       │   search.html
│   │       │   searchindex.js
│   │       │   src.html
│   │       │
│   │       ├───_sources
│   │       │       index.rst.txt
│   │       │       modules.rst.txt
│   │       │       src.rst.txt
│   │       │
│   │       └───_static
│   │               alabaster.css
│   │               basic.css
│   │               custom.css
│   │               doctools.js
│   │               documentation_options.js
│   │               file.png
│   │               jquery-3.5.1.js
│   │               jquery.js
│   │               language_data.js
│   │               minus.png
│   │               plus.png
│   │               pygments.css
│   │               searchtools.js
│   │               underscore-1.3.1.js
│   │               underscore.js
│   │
│   └───source
│       │   conf.py
│       │   index.rst
│       │   modules.rst
│       │   src.rst
│       │
│       ├───_static
│       └───_templates
└───src
        nopes.py
        sqrer.py
        __init__.py
```

And here is my `conf.py`:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.

import os
import sys
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve() / '..' / '..' / '..' / 'src'

# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..\src'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(path))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'TEST PROJECT'
copyright = '2020, Cerberton'
author = 'Cerberton'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'alabaster'

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']


# -- Extension configuration -------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../src'))`. The path to `src` must be relative to `conf.py`. Also I don't know what that stuff is for the `path` variable you declared, but it looks... uh... creative.